# What is Lupin III's nationality?

Tags: lupin-the-third

Apparently, in *Lupin III: Green Vs. Red*, Zenigata is seen with a file that states Lupin's place of birth as unknown. However, according to [this page](http://lupin.wikia.com/wiki/Arsene_Lupin_III#Origins), this particular work is not considered canon.

Lupin often refers to himself as French, Zenigata often says he's Japanese and on one occasion Lupin himself stated he's half-French, half-Japanese.
We know both his grandfather and father were French, but we know nothing about his mother (at least I think not).

Is there any source that states where he was born, what his mother's nationality is, or anything else that might suggest his nationality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the sources stated that Lupin III is half-French, half-Japanese - sources: [1](http://lupin-iii.generalanswers.org/), [2](http://wikipedia.qwika.com/de2en/Lupin_III#Ars.C3.A8ne_Lupin_III), [3](http://lupin.wikia.com/wiki/Arsene_Lupin_III#Origins), [4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars%C3%A8ne_Lupin_III). There are also sources that state that his nationality is unknown - sources: [1](http://www.lupinthethird.info/personages/char_lupin_en.html), [2](http://www.lupinencyclopedia.com/profiles/characters/arsene_lupin_iii). But according to [this](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/LupinIII):

> Lupin is half-French, half-Japanese, though Monkey Punch, Lupin's creator himself said (in materials to promote the first Lupin movie) that he considered Lupin to be of no nationality – a citizen of the world.